# Views Slideshow: how to change items per slide based on screen resolution

Tags: 8

I have a Views Slideshow slider with 3 items per slide (see below).

I am looking for a way to make it change the items per slide number dynamically when the screen width hits a certain breakpoint -for example 2 items per slide on tablet screen and 1 item per slide on mobile screen.

Been trying for few days but without success.
I'm able to access the number of slides in the JSON
 var slideNumber = drupalSettings.viewsSlideshowCycle["#views_slideshow_cycle_main_publications_featured_slider-block_1"].items_per_slide;

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We use the [Owl carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel) for this.  It lets you specify four breakpoints and the number of slides to show.

There is a D8 recommendation for [Flickity](https://www.drupal.org/project/flickity) but it has some licensing restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do this in a custom way. Output the view in a simple unordered list and use a is library for the carousel. Owl carousel is my favourite, it's got the responsiveness you require.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with Kevin howbrook and CG Monroe to use owl carousel module or alternative , but You can alter Drupal JS variables by implementing **hook_js_settings_alter** in your module,

```
function MYMODULE_js_settings_alter(array &$settings, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  if (isset($settings['viewsSlideshowCycle'])) {
    $settings['viewsSlideshowCycle']['#views_slideshow_cycle_main_publications_featured_slider-block_1']['items_per_slide'] = '1';
  }
}
```